# Validating Year with DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime

I have this block of code for validating a correctly formatted date prior to submission to a DB insert using [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). I'm expecting the date format to convert 'DD/MM/YYYY' to 'YYYY-MM-DD' or else raise an error.

```
$dateofbirth = trim($_POST['dateofbirth']);
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateofbirth);

$date_errors = DateTime::getLastErrors();
    var_dump($date_errors);
if ($date_errors['warning_count'] + $date_errors['error_count'] > 0) {
    $dobError = 'Date '.$dateofbirth.' is not a valid DD/MM/YYYY format.';
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $mysql_dob = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
error_log($dateofbirth.' -> '.$mysql_dob);
```

This date works

```
 $dateofbirth = '30/11/1980'; => 1980-11-30
```

but this one fail silently

```
 $dateofbirth = '30/11/80'; => 0080-11-30
```

since i'm expecting to be notified of the missing century digits. I've read the formatting rules and am using the upper case 'Y' which should ensure a 4 digit year. Any idea's where i'm going wrong?

EDIT

1 - Correct the test date as per OneTrickPony's comment

2 - I added a var_dump of the $date_errors variable. Since the format is 'd/m/Y' and the input is '30/11/80' i am expecting an error or warning but i don't get one.

```
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
30/11/80 -> 0080-11-30
```

Comment: It doesn't fail silently: http://3v4l.org/bap8p

Comment: @Gordon thx for [3v4l.org](http://www.3v4l.org), looks cool!

Comment: Note that November has 30 days only ;)

Comment: @Gordon 3v4l.org seems pretty slick http://3v4l.org/muLLh

Comment: As a workaround, you can first check with a Regex pattern for the correct format and then with DateTime for the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `DateTime::createFromFormat`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure.
```

So rather than checking `getLastErrors` you should check if `$date === false`

Change your error check to:

```
if ($date === false) {
    $dobError = 'Date '.$dateofbirth.' is not a valid DD/MM/YYYY format.';
    $hasError = true;
} else {
    $mysql_dob = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateofbirth);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> This date works
>
> ```
> $dateofbirth = '30/11/1980'; => 1980-11-30
> ```
>
> but this one fail silently
>
> ```
> $dateofbirth = '30/11/80'; => 0080-11-30
> ```

According to the [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) manual page, the format you provided very expressly looks for a *four digit* year.  It's parsing "80" as the year 80 AD instead of 1980.

To accept a two digit year, you would need to use a *lowercase* `y` instead of an uppercase `Y`.  However, this would also then not accept a four digit year.

Your options are:

1. Validate that the user entered the correct string length before encountering date validation code.
2. Use string length to determine the format used
3. Use a regex to check the length of the year and change the format accordingly
4. If you're breaking out regexes, you'd may as well just use [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/checkdate)
5. Stop accepting dates in the *very weird, nonstandard* DD/MM/YYYY format.  Where slashes are commonly used, the expected format is actually MM/DD/YYYY instead, which may create significant user confusion.

Comment: DD/MM/YYYY isn't "very weird". It actually [more common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)